# Setting text in EditText causing app crash

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am programming an app in Android Studio. I am taking json file from server, then extracting it to strings and want to show in EditText to let it be modifiable.

Here my code

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... atr) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int success;
                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", table_name));


                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_product_details, "GET", params);
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        String _name = product.getString("name");
                        name.setText(_name, EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                        if(!product.isNull("price")) {
                            Integer _price = product.getInt("price");
                            price.setText(_price, EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                        }
                        if(!product.isNull("quantity")) {
                            Integer _quantity = product.getInt("quantity");
                            quantity.setText(_quantity, EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                        }
                        if(!product.isNull("promotion")) {
                            Integer _promotion = product.getInt("promotion");
                            promotion.setText(_promotion, EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
                        i.putExtra("list_name", table_name);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        return null;
    }
```

unfortunately, when I am trying like this app crashes when i try upload text to EditText. I confirmed that EditText isn't null, Strings too. There is no error message what impede this problem. Have anybody some idea? I looked everywhere (maybe i can't search xD) and didn't find anything reasonable.

Comment: You can't do it in `doInbackground()` . You need to do it on `onPostExecute()` method

Answer (score 0):

First thing, unwrap your code from that Thread. `doInBackground()` is already asynchronous, so there it's redundant. Either use a Thread or an AsyncTask, not both.

Second thing, Views, such as EditText, can only be modified on the *main* or UI Thread. When you run `setText()`, or *any* other methods on View, it needs to be on the main Thread.

If this is inside an Activity, you can use:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //appropriate setText()
    }
});
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use a Handler. Create a global variable:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

and instead of using `runOnUiThread()`, use `handler.post()`, with the same syntax (just replace `runOnUiThread` with `handler.post`).

However, there's also a third thing. You shouldn't really be handling your JSON String in the background. You should only be retrieving the String at that point. Your logic should go in `onPostExecute()`, which already executes on the main Thread for you.

Your code should look like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... atr) {
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", table_name));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_product_details, "GET", params);
        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            return json; //return the JSON String on success
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
            i.putExtra("list_name", table_name);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null; //return null for any other result
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (result != null) { //make sure result isn't null
        JSONArray productObj = result.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);
        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

        String _name = product.getString("name");
        name.setText(_name, EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        if (!product.isNull("price")) {
            Integer _price = product.getInt("price");
            price.setText(_price, EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }
        if (!product.isNull("quantity")) {
            Integer _quantity = product.getInt("quantity");
            quantity.setText(_quantity, EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }
        if (!product.isNull("promotion")) {
            Integer _promotion = product.getInt("promotion");
            promotion.setText(_promotion, EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are interacting with any UI element, like EditText, you can't use anything other than UI thread (or main thread).

In other words, UI elements must be changed from UI thread.

What you can do:

1. Move codes where UI element(like EditText) is updated from doInBackground(String... str) to onPostExecuted(String str).
2. Every time you use any UI element from another thread, use View.post(Runnable runnable) method. Like:

   ```
   editText.post(
           new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   //do your work
               }
           }
   );
   ```

   or use Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) method when within an Activity

   ```
    runOnUiThread(
           new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   //do your work
               }
           }
   );
   ```